# How to send data by clicking on a label for a checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to submit a form by clicking on a label for a checkbox. The checkbox isn't shown, and the label is styled as a button. This is my code:

```
<%= form_tag(fetch_games_index_path, method: :get, id: 'games-filter-form', remote: true) do %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'mobile[]', 'true', false, id: 'games-filter-checkbox', class: 'games-filter-checkbox' %>
  <label for="games-filter-checkbox" id="game-mobile-0"></label>
<% end %>
```

And corresponding js:

```
$('#game-mobile-0').click(function () {
    $('#games-filter-form input[type="hidden"]').submit();
});
```

By doing this, when I click on a label for the first time, it sets the checkbox to `true`, but the sent params are empty. When I click the label for once again, the checkbox sets to `false`, and I can see in params: `"mobile"=>["true"]`. I tried the following code:

```
$('#game-mobile-0').click(function () {
  if($('#games-filter-checkbox').prop('checked', true)) {
    $('#games-filter-form input[type="hidden"]').submit();
  }
});
```

but doing this, the animation of the label, which is styled doesn't work. What is the way to fix this issue? Thanks ahead.

[image: animated_button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code helped:

```
$('#game-mobile-0').click(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#games-filter-form input[type="hidden"]').submit();
  }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you SET the value in the conditional rather than reference its value.

```
$('#game-mobile-0').click(function () {
  if($('#games-filter-checkbox').prop('checked', true)) {
    $('#games-filter-form input[type="hidden"]').submit();
  }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value

```
$('#game-mobile-0').click(function () {
   // cache a reference
   var checkitem = $('#games-filter-checkbox');
   // set to the value it is NOT at present (check if not, un-check if checked)
   checkitem.prop('checked', !checkitem[0].checked)
   // if checked now, submit
   if(checkitem[0].checked) {
       // submit form with this id:
       $('#games-filter-form').submit();
   }
});
```

Comment: Still, the issue remains. It submits the form and doesn't animate my styled label.

Comment: what is the animation? When the form is submitted you want to change the label style to something else?

Comment: styling the label does not have anything to do with submitting the form. if you want to change the style when the submit happens you should use jquery addclass or css methods e.g. `.$('#game-mobile-0').removeClass( "oldClass").addClass( "newClass" );` after the `$('#games-filter-form').submit();`

Comment: Just added a screenshot of a button

Comment: Styling is a different issue and different question perhaps - i.e. How do I style an image over a checkbox?  or some such question, style has nothing to do with the submit of the form.  Note some browsers will not submit hidden fields on a form - you can search for that issue elsewhere.